# how to debug what's wrong with mailx

Tags: mailx

I'm trying to see what happening why my mailx is failing. I tried to run the mailx command locally with a debug flag but it just returns a empty carriage return.

Once it showed me this error.

**SSL/TLS handshake failed: Unknown error -5938**

on my /var/log/messages file, it says

**crond: sendmail: Cannot open smtps4.company.com:587**

I would love to deep dive what's wrong but the line is just too unhelpful. What are other places I can check to see what happening behind the scenes so I can see what's causing the issue?

I'm pretty sure the mail server that I am trying to connect to is up since it is being used in prod environment. I"m trying in dev environment. Both ports 587 and 465 are open. But still it won't push through sending the email.

I'm using the same configuration as what is in our prod server